# Set a value from a variable to one properties from the application.properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to set a value of my `application.properties`, I need to set there the path of a file.

I know I can do this:

```java
@Value("${catalog.path:theValuePath}")
private String absolutePath;
```

but I got the value from a method, so I was trying something like this

```java
@Value("${catalog.path}")
private String absolutePath=setCatalogPath();

public String setCatalogPath () {
    File file = new File("src/test/resources/MyFile.xml");
    String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    return absolutePath;
}
```

It's not working and I guess is not the ideal way what I'm doing, any ideas? thanks in advance

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at below example. You can apply the @Value annotation in class to be auto wired.Make sure to write getters and setters to the absolutePath variable instead of assigning a value through assignment operator.Then use the get method to get the value back for application.

1. Data class

   ```
    @Component
    public class Data {
        @Value("${catalog.path:theValuePath}")
        private String absolutePath;

        public String getAbsolutePath() {
            return absolutePath;
        }

        public void setAbsolutePath(String absolutePath) {
            this.absolutePath = absolutePath;
        }
   ```
2. Returning the value through a method

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public class Mycon {


        @Autowired
        Data data;
        @GetMapping
        public String hello(ModelMap model) {

            return data.getAbsolutePath();

        }

    }
```

3. Application.properties file

```
    catalog.path:theValuePath="src/test/resources/MyFile.xml"
```